Retrieve selected fields from a search
I would like to retrieve only a few fields from a search in Elasticsearch run via Java client. In version 7 of the API, I used the following code:
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.fetchSource( new String [] {"A", "B"}, null );

How can I do this using the API of version 8?

check this: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-java-api-client-about-source-filtering-function/321173

for Elasticsearch version 8, there is no fetchSource, so you can try this:
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest.Builder()
    .index("index_name")
    .query(query)
    .source(SourceConfig.of(s -> s.filter(f -> f.includes(List.of("field_A", "field_B")))))
    .build();

SourceConfig gives access to include and exclude fields.
I guess this is the only way, if you find another way please update us and post it in your question.

With your code I have the following error:
The method of(String, String) is undefined for the type List.
The include method accepts a list of strings, so I solved it like this:
.includes("field_A", "field_B")

In the meantime I had written the following code that works:
.source(so -> so.filter(sf -> sf.includes("field_A", "field_B")))

I didn't test my code, but I am happy it worked with you after adjustments.
